# Proof that only finitely many terms of the sequence are outside a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers with limit $a$, satisfying $1 < a < 2$. Prove that only finitely many terms of $a_n$ lie outside $(1,2)$.

I attempted to proceed directly, taking $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Then there exists an $N$ so that for $n > N$, $|a_n - a| < \frac{1}{2}$. Then $a - \frac{1}{2} < a_n < a + \frac{1}{2}$. If $a = 2$, then this doesn't guarantee $a_n \in [1,2]$ for $n > N$. I'm not sure if there is a 'small enough' $\epsilon$, so I could try a proof by contradiction. Suppose that infinitely many terms lie outside $[1,2]$. Then I should be able to find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $N$, there exists $n > N$, such that $|a_n - a| \geq \epsilon$. I can't manage to think of an appropriate $\epsilon$, however, that will work for every $N$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the condition is not $1<a<2$? otherwise you can simply take $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$; then $a_n\notin [1,2]$ for all $n$, but $\lim_n a_n=1$

Comment: That must be the condition. I'll edit the post, thanks.

Comment: Hint: choose an $\varepsilon$ such that $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon) \subset (1,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $1<a<2$, we have that $a-1>0$ and $2-a>0$, so $\min\{a-1,2-a\}>0$. Pick an $\varepsilon$ less than $\min\{a-1,2-a\}$. Then for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$a-\varepsilon<a_n<a+\varepsilon\text{ for every }n>N$$

Since $\varepsilon<\min\{a-1,2-a\}$, we have that $\varepsilon<a-1$ and $\varepsilon<2-a$, so $a-\varepsilon>1$ and $a+\varepsilon<2$. This implies that $1<a_n<2$ for every $n>N$, so we are done.